# How to test custom gradle task against test project directory

Tags: gradle, gradle-custom-plugin

I have custom gradle plugin with such task:

```
@TaskAction
def buildSemanticVersion() {
    int major = project.semanticVersion.major
    int minor = project.semanticVersion.minor
    int patch = "git rev-list HEAD --count".execute().text.toInteger()

    project.setVersion("${major}.${minor}.${patch}")
}
```

I have integration test for it:

```
@Test
public void testBuildSemanticVersion() throws Exception {
    // GIVEN
    Project project = ProjectBuilder.builder().withProjectDir(new File("build/tmp/git-repository")).build()
    project.apply plugin: 'com.github.moleksyuk.vcs-semantic-version'
    project.semanticVersion.with { major = 1; minor = 2 }

    // WHEN
    project.tasks.buildSemanticVersion.execute()

    // THEN
    assertThat(project.version, Matchers.equalTo('1.2.3'))
}
```

But it fails because my command **"git rev-list HEAD --count".execute().text.toInteger()** in task is executed agains my project dir but not against my test dir **"build/tmp/git-repository"**.

Is it possible to execute this task agains test project directory?

**Update:**

Thanks to @Mark Vieira and @Rene Groeschke. According to their suggestion I fixed it in such way:

```
@TaskAction
def buildSemanticVersion() {
    int major = project.semanticVersion.major
    int minor = project.semanticVersion.minor

    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    def execResult = project.exec({
        commandLine 'git'
        args 'rev-list', 'HEAD', '--count'
        standardOutput = stdout;
    })

    int patch = stdout.toString().toInteger()

    project.setVersion("${major}.${minor}.${patch}")
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using Gradle's `Project.exec()` rather than the Groovy mechanism, which would allow you to set the working directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

groovys `"...".execute()` always uses the current working directory of the java process and as far as I know it is not configurable.

This failing test already shows a problem with your task implementation as the working directory is not necessarily the project directory. you could use an `Exec` task or wrap the `project.exec` method into your own task. both, project.exec and Exec allow you to configure the working directory.

Comment: Thanks Rene and Mark. Your suggestion works perfect.